# Simple C# Rest Service routing

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have made a simple WCF Rest service. In my Global.asax I register routes, like

```
private void RegisterRoutes()
{
   RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Test", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Test)));
   RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Account", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Account)));
}
```

This means that when I go to `http://192.168.0.1/Test/HelloWorld` I call the method HelloWorld in the Test class. But if I go to `http://192.168.0.1` I get a `http 403.14 Forbidden` message. I want to map / to /Test. Is it possible? I've tried replacing "Test" with "*" and "" but if I do so, all calls go to Test...

Comment: Ah, so that's the reason why I don't get a lot of answers... Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was as simple as adding the line

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Test)));
```

after the other lines in RegisterRoutes() method.